# Using Noise Model of a real hardware on qiskit simulators

Tags: qiskit, programming, noise

I am trying to understand how to use the noise model of real hardware. Below is the part of the code I have written with the help of sample codes from these links:

qiskit.github.io/qiskit-aer/apidocs/aer_noise.html

qiskit-community.github.io/qiskit-algorithms/tutorials/…

qiskit.github.io/qiskit-aer/tutorials/index.html

I have a lot of questions which I still not able to understand.
What is `depolarizing_error` ? Are we adding somekind of error to the existing errors of `ibm_cairo` ? I have added some gates to the API `add_all_qubit_quantum_error`?How can I know what all gates I have in my quantum circuit? Can I use `qasm_simulator` instead of `AerSimulator`. If possible then how?

```
    prob_1 = 0.001  # 1-qubit gate
    prob_2 = 0.01   # 2-qubit gate
    
    # Depolarizing quantum errors
    error_1 = noise.depolarizing_error(prob_1, 1) # I think, one means here 1 qubit
    error_2 = noise.depolarizing_error(prob_2, 2) # I think, two means here 2 qubit
    
    # Add errors to noise model
    noise_model = noise.NoiseModel()
    
    noise_model.add_all_qubit_quantum_error(error_1, ['u1', 'u2', 'u3','x','y','z','h','s','t'])  
    
    noise_model.add_all_qubit_quantum_error(error_2, ['cx','cy','cz', 'swap'])
    
    
    # Get basis gates from noise model
    basis_gates = noise_model.basis_gates
    
    # provider = IBMQ.load_account()
    provider = IBMQ.get_provider(hub=' ', group=' ', project=' ')
    backend_cairo = provider.get_backend('ibm_cairo')
    
    
    noise_model = NoiseModel.from_backend(backend_cairo)
    
    # Get coupling map from backend
    coupling_map = backend_cairo.configuration().coupling_map
    # Perform a noise simulation
    backend = AerSimulator(noise_model=noise_model,
                        coupling_map=coupling_map,
    
                        basis_gates=basis_gates)
    transpiled_circuit = transpile(qc_combine, backend)
    result = backend.run(transpiled_circuit, shots= self.shots_done).result()
```

**Edit**
If the modify the code as below, then how backend getting the NoiseModel. Please review.

```
provider = IBMQ.get_provider(hub=' ', group=' ', project=' ')
backend_cairo = provider.get_backend('ibm_cairo')
                                  
noise_model = NoiseModel.from_backend(backend_cairo)
backend = AerSimulator.from_backend(backend_cairo)
```

Comment: (1) You need to load the account before getting the provider `if IBMQ.active_account() is None: IBMQ.load_account()`
(2) You need to pass valid values for `hub`, `group`, and `project` (e.g., `IBMQ.get_provider(hub='ibm-q', group='open', project='main')`)
(3) Make sure you have access to the backend ibm_cairo ([here](https://quantum.ibm.com/services/resources) is the list of available backends)

Comment: After putting details of hub, group and project, the above code works well @Egretta.Thula.  My question is that do I have to put the `noise_model` some how as a argument in `backend = AerSimulator.from_backend(backend_cairo)` like `backend = AerSimulator.from_backend(backend_cairo, noise_model= noise_model)`?

Comment: You don't need to pass `noise_model`.

Comment: Thank you @Egretta.Thula for great help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If all what you want is to derive a noise model from the properties of a real quantum device, then you just need to use [`NoiseModel.from_backend()`](https://qiskit.github.io/qiskit-aer/stubs/qiskit_aer.noise.NoiseModel.html#qiskit_aer.noise.NoiseModel.from_backend) method:

```python
noise_model = NoiseModel.from_backend(backend_cairo)
```

Methods like `add_all_qubit_quantum_error()` are needed if you want to build your own custom noise model.

If, however, you want your simulator to mimic the other real device properties like coupling map and basis gateset in addition to the noise model, then you can call [`AerSimulator.from_backend()`](https://qiskit.github.io/qiskit-aer/stubs/qiskit_aer.AerSimulator.html#qiskit_aer.AerSimulator.from_backend)

```python
simulator = AerSimulator.from_backend(backend)
```